# Program not finding file in same folder

Tags: java

I have to create a histogram based on grades students received that are in a text file named "midterm.txt.". I've posted what I've come up with so far, but to be honest I don't know if I'm even on the right path because I can't get the program to run to see how it behaves. To explain my thought process with what I have currently, I made several lists with grades and then try to read each integer within the file and match the integer it reads with the int's I defined. If it matches, it will add to that count. Below it I am outputting each count just to see if it's working (except program doesn't run.) If I can confirm that its counting then I'll create a histogram. Also below is my error I get in eclipse.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class classGrades {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File("midterm.txt");
        Scanner grades = new Scanner(file);
        int[] a = {71, 72, 73, 74, 75};
        int[] b = {76, 77, 78, 79, 80};
        int[] c = {81, 82, 83, 84, 85};
        int[] d = {86, 87, 88 , 89, 90};
        int[] e = {91, 92, 93, 94, 95};
        int[] f = {96, 97, 98, 99, 100};
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        int three = 0;
        int four = 0;
        int five = 0;
        int six = 0;
        while(grades.hasNextLine()){
            int grade = grades.nextInt();
            if(grade == a.length){
                one++;
            } else if(grade == b.length){
                two++;
            } else if(grade == c.length){
                three++;
            } else if(grade == d.length){
                four++;
            } else if(grade == e.length){
                five++;
            } else if(grade == f.length){
                six++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(one);
        System.out.println(two);
        System.out.println(three);
        System.out.println(four);
        System.out.println(five);
        System.out.println(six);
    }
}
```

The error I get in console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: midterm.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at classGrades.main(classGrades.java:6)
```

Comment: Your working directory is probably not what you think it is. Try `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());`.

Comment: Okay so I've done that and got: D:\Java\Program Assignment 2\midterm.txt. I then altered my file statement to: File file = new File("D:\Java\Program Assignment 2\midterm.txt"); And that didn't work

Comment: @aioobe 's suggestion shouldn't output a file's absolute path such as `D:\Java\Program Assignment 2\midterm.txt`, it should probably output `D:\Java\Program Assignment 2\ `, since `.` is the current directory, unless you have a directory in your project named `midterm.txt`.

Comment: what IDE are you using?